# General Topology - separation axiom

Tags: general-topology

Recall that $a$ is an accumulation point of a set $A$ in a space X if and only if each neighborhood of $a$ meets $A$ in some point other than $a$. We say $a$ is a condensation point of $A$ if and only if each neighborhood of $a$ meets $A$ in uncountably many points. Let $A^{\prime}$ denote the set of accumulation points of $A$, and let $A_c$ denote the set of condensation points of $A$.

How do I prove that, In a T1-space, $a$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if and only if each neighborhood of $a$ meets $A$ in an infinite set?

Furthermore, how do I prove that for any set $A$, $A^{\prime}$ and $A_c$ are closed sets, with $A_c \subseteq A^{\prime}$?

Comment: prove that in a T1 space, a is an accumulation point of A iff each nhood of a meets A in an infinite set

Comment: @nuarslandogan Start from the definition of a T1 space. Remember that in T1 spaces, distinct points $a,b$ have open neighborhoods $a\in X, b\in Y$ with $b\not\in X$ and $a\not\in Y$. How can you use that, and the fact that $a$ is an accumulation point of $A$, to imply that a neighborhood of $a$ meets $A$ at infinitely many points?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part: Let $a$ be an accumulation point of $A.$ If possible, let us assume that $U$ is a neighbourhood of $a,$ such that $U\cap A$ is finite and $U\cap A=\{a,a_1,\cdots,a_n\}.$ Since we are in a $T_1$ space, so for the pair $a,a_i$ of distinct points ($1\le i\le n$), there exist open sets $U_i$ and $V_i,$ satisfying $a\in U_i,~a_i\in V_i,~a\not\in V_i,~a_i\not\in U_i.$ So the neighbourhood $U\cap U_1\cap\cdots\cap U_n$ of $a$ does not contain the points $a_i,~1\le i\le n.$ In other words, it contains only one point of $A,$ which is $a.$ This is a contradiction to our hypothesis that $a$ is an accumulation point of $A.$ So our assumption is wrong and $U\cap A$ must be infinite for every neighbourhood of $a.$

Conversely, let $U\cap A$ be an infinite set for each neighbourhood $U$ of $a.$ Then it is obvious that $(U\cap A)-\{a\}\not=\emptyset.$ Hence $a$ is an accumulation point of $A.$

For the second part: Showing that $A'$ is closed is equivalent to showing that $X-A'$ is open, where $X$ is the $T_1$ space concerned. If $X=A',$ then we are done. So assume that $X\not=A'$ and let $x\in X-A'.$ Then $x$ is not an accumulation point of $A.$ So there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x,$ such that $U\cap A$ is $\emptyset$ or $\{x\}.$ Let me claim that $U\cap A'=\emptyset.$ If not, then there exists some $b\in U\cap A'.$ This simply means that $b$ is an accumulation point of $A$ (since $b\in A'$) and $U$ is a neighbourhood of $b.$ Hence $(U\cap A)-\{b\}$ is infinite (by the first part). But this is impossible, since $U\cap A$ is $\emptyset$ or $\{a\}.$ Hence my claim is established and so $U\subseteq X-A'.$ Since $x\in U,$ $U$ is open and $x$ is an arbitrarily chosen point of $X-A'$ and so $X-A'$ is open.

The closedness of $A_c$ can be similarly shown. Also, the inclusion $A_c\subseteq A'$ follows directly from the definitions of $A_c,A'.$